# jquery set property error, help in overcoming this please

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to set a property using jquery i'm new to doing this so i could well be making a very simple mistake or this might not be appropriate for what im trying to achieve

Here is my query where I try to set a variable - [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PiWH.png)

here is how I try to pass the `access_token` from the response to a property - [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL74X.png)

here is the error i get when i debug the code `'ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined'`- [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3TP0.png)

can anyone give me some advice on how i can overcome the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution to my problem

```
 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        ID = response['access_token'];
        console.log(ID)
      });
   

    // if hard coded the token
    private ACCESS_TOKEN : string = ID;
```